# Adding an element to the end of a stream for each element already in the stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, concatenation

Given a function `Function<T, T> f` and a `Stream<T> ts` what is a good (nice readability, good performance) way of creating a new `Stream<T>` which first contains the original elements and then the elements converted by `f`.

One might think this would work:

```
Stream.concat(ts, ts.map(f));
```

But this doesn't work and results in an exception instead:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

*Note*: that the order does matter: original elements have to come first in correct order, then the transformed elements in matching order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't open a bottle of wine and then pass the bottle to another person and ask him to open it *again*.

Thus I think this is not possible by the *nature* of streams to do what you ask for.

You have **one** chain of "processing" per stream. You can't have **two**.

So the closest you could get at would be working from "its origin", like

```
Stream.concat(someList.stream(), someList.stream().map(f));
```

for example. And of course, when you don't have that list, you could go for:

```
List<Whatever> someList = ts.collect(Collectors.asList());
```

first.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement a `Spliterator` that wraps your source stream. Internally, you will create the "duplicate" element for each processed one, and then switch to those duplicates once the source is empty:

```
public class Duplicates<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
    private Spliterator<T> source;

    private Consumer<T>    addDuplicate;

    private Builder<T>     extrasStreamBuilder = Stream.builder();
    private Spliterator<T> extrasSpliterator;

    private Duplicates(Stream<T> source, UnaryOperator<T> f) {
        this.addDuplicate = t -> extrasStreamBuilder.add(f.apply(t));
        this.source = source.spliterator();
    }

    public static <T> Stream<T> of(Stream<T> source, UnaryOperator<T> f) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Duplicates<>(source, f), false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        boolean advanced = false;

        if (extrasSpliterator == null) {
            advanced = source.tryAdvance(addDuplicate.andThen(action));
        }

        if (!advanced) {
            if (extrasSpliterator == null) {
                extrasSpliterator = extrasStreamBuilder.build().spliterator();
            }
            advanced = extrasSpliterator.tryAdvance(action);
        }

        return advanced;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (extrasSpliterator == null) {
            source.forEachRemaining(addDuplicate.andThen(action));
            extrasSpliterator = extrasStreamBuilder.build().spliterator();
        }

        extrasSpliterator.forEachRemaining(action);
    }

    // other spliterator methods worked with default (Eclipse) implementation for the example below, but should probably delegate to source
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    Stream<String> wrapper = Duplicates.of(input.stream(), i -> i + "0");

    wrapper.forEach(System.out::println);
}

// Output:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 10
// 20
// 30
```

It might depend on your use case whether this is efficient enough in regards of memory consumption as you keep the `extras` in the stream builder.

The advantage over collecting and mapping ahead of your actual stream processing is that you only traverse the source once. This might be helpful when retrieving the elements takes long or the order of elements can change between streams.

You are also able to first chain some stream operations to the source before duplicating, again without having to collect the intermediate result into a collection.

Comment: I have not looked into details, but a `Spliterator` *is* the way to go in such cases; this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The `Spliterator` would greatly benefit from a dedicated `forEachRemaining` implementation. Also, I would add a `extrasSpliterator==null` check before polling the source spliterator to avoid polling over and over again when its iteration has been completed.

Comment: @Holger I was waiting for your input already. I added the null check and `forEachRemaining`. Is the implementation any useful like that? What advantage does `forEachRemaining` have? What overhead of `tryAdvance` does it avoid? And would it improve the situation if we called `extrasBuilder.build().forEach(action)` instead of going through the spliterator?

Comment: Under the current implementation, `f.andThen(action)` constructs a new `Consumer` instance each time, as it captures `f` and `action`. So `forEachRemaining` does it only once. Also, it avoids a lot of conditionals to be evaluated per-element with `tryAdvance`. It looks quiet reasonable, but you could move the first statement into the `if` block, `if(extrasSpliterator==null) { source.forEachRemaining( f.andThen(action)); extrasSpliterator = extrasStreamBuilder.build().spliterator(); }`.

Comment: Looks really nice and probably the right thing to do if one needs this more often, but in my case, it is too much effort for one-off usage.

Comment: Of course, all these things might get also handled by the optimizer, but as long as the work on the source code side stays reasonable, I wouldn’t rely on the optimizer to do it. In this regard, the difference between `extrasBuilder.build().forEach(action)` and `extrasStreamBuilder.build().spliterator().forEachRemaining(action)` will be too small, if any at all, to justify a complication of the code. Keep in mind that you must be handle scenarios where `tryAdvance gets called a few times before  a final `forEachRemaining` call.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: indeed, for a one-off usage, collecting into a temporary list might be much simpler. You may consider the alternative of using `stream.toArray()` and `Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(array), Arrays.stream(array).map(f));`…

Answer (score 3):

When it's only for the elements and not for the order (first the original items, then the modified), you could use flatMap:

```
Stream<T> s = ...;
Stream<T> result = s.flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x, f.apply(x));
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If the order is relevant, one could ask why you want to use streams, because you won't benefit from lazy evaluation...

Comment: The order does matter, will clarify in question.

Comment: Regarding the fact, that streams can possibly be infinite, you would have to have an infinite cache to process this. _#justsaying_

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But of course, the operation would be completely useless with an infinite stream, just as many other operations (concat, many uses of collect)

Comment: afaik a function taking a stream and producing one should be as lazy as possible (as concat will not touch the second stream as long as the first one is not done), but this may be a philosophical discussion.

Comment: But there is no inherent problem in implementing this lazy. And the buffer size is limited to the # of elements you are actually retrieving from the resulting Stream.